# Phone app: item cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, sdk

I am trying to follow a manual (which had some bugs and I fixed it) however I am receiving this error `btstart cannot be resolved or is not a field` and I don't know how to fix it. Here's the [LINK](http://www.mydoople.com/android-stopwatch-example) to that manual (but I have done changes in layout as well as string xml files) Here is the MainActivity.java code :

```
 package com.example.stopwatch;
//import com.example.stopwatch.R;
import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private Button start;
    private Button stop;
    private Button reset;

    private Chronometer mydChronometer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        uI();
    }

    public void uI() {
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btstart);
        start.setOnClickListener(this);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btstop);
        stop.setOnClickListener(this);
        reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btreset);
        reset.setOnClickListener(this);
        mydChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == start) {
            mydChronometer.start();

        } else if (v == stop) {

            mydChronometer.stop();
        } else if (v== reset) {
            mydChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

        }

    }

}
```

Here comes my "activity_main.xml" :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chronometer1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:src="@drawable/myd" />

    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/chronometer1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Chronometer"
        android:textSize="35dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btstart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chronometer1"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="@string/start" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btreset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btstop"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btstop"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btstop"
        android:text="@string/reset" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btstop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btstart"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btstart"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btstart"
        android:text="@string/stop" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's the "strings.xml" file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">stopwatch</string>
    <string name="btn1">Start</string>
    <string name="btn2">Stop</string>
    <string name="btn3">Reset</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

</resources>
```

I haven't done any change in main.xml and here is my main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```

Could you please let me know what am I missing and what's the fix to this error?

P.S.: I am receiving similar error for these lines:

```
btstop cannot be resolved or is not a field in stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btstop);
btreset cannot be resolved or is not a field in reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btreset);
chronometer1 cannot be resolved or is not a field in mydChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
```

Thanks a ton.

Comment: Clean and rebuild your app.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I cleaned the project now and (Ctrl+B) (build all) is inactive and when I press it nothing happens! And I have this new error `R cannot be resolved to a variable` added in this line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` Any idea how to resolve these errors?

Answer (score 3):

Like Sotirios said, try clean the project, then in Project => uncheck clean automatically, then now you can build your project individually.

Comment: thanks for your hint! I was able to build it manually with your hint after I cleaned the project! That all being said yet I have the problem I mentioned `activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field` in this line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` I have also used "Shift+Ctrl+O" to include all the necessary libraries. I am really clueless what's wrong as I have checked all the possible solution in other Stackoverflow links.thanks!

Comment: <string name="reset">Reset</string>
    <string name="reset">Stop</string>
so basically there is no such string name="stop" so your main.xml can't be compiled.

Comment: I suggest you double check all resources like string, drawable, make sure you've included their path correctly.

Answer (score 0):

See this ["id cannot be resolved or is not a field" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296047/id-cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-a-field-error) it may help you.

Look if you re importing android .R

That could be the error

Comment: Actually I saw this post and tried all the solution, none of them helpful!

Answer (score 0):

R not being resolved is a result of the *R.java*  file not being generated automatically.

Check for errors in your resources folder, as this is what the *R.java* automatic generation is based on. In my case, in my *AndroidManifest.xml* file, I had to change one of the lines from

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/*icon"* android:label="@string/app_name">
```

to

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/*ic_launcher"* android:label="@string/app_name">
```

(i.e. change the `@drawable/icon` to the name of the *.png* file in the *resources (res) folder*