# id cannot be resolved or is not a field, Button listener

Tags: android

I'm pretty sure i'm missing something really easy here... I'm new to android so i'm sorry about this. I think i'm not linking the buttons to the listener properly, basicly what I think i'm doing is making a listner (for buttons) and checking which button has been pushed,

## MainMenu.java

```
package com.coursework;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class mainMenu extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);

    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gameName);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "RetroElectro.ttf");
    txt.setTypeface(font);


    Button.OnClickListener listener = new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(v.id == R.id.play){
                Log.w("Test","one");
            }
else if(v.id == R.id.options){
                Log.w("Test","one");
            }

        }

};
((Button)findViewById(R.id.play)).setOnClickListener(listener);
```

}
  }

## XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>

      <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/gameName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/gameName"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textSize="80sp"
    />

  <Button
    android:layout_width="@dimen/button"
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:text="@string/play"></Button>




  <Button
    android:layout_width="@dimen/button"
    android:id="@+id/options"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/play"
    android:text="@string/options"></Button>
   <Button
    android:layout_width="@dimen/button"
    android:id="@+id/scoreboard"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/options"
    android:text="@string/score"></Button>
    <Button
    android:layout_width="@dimen/button"
    android:id="@+id/exit"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/scoreboard"
    android:text="@string/exit"></Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The part which is the problem is the line `if(v.id == R.id.play){` and `if(v.id == R.id.play){` with an error,

`id cannot be resolved or is not a field`

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296047/id-cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-a-field-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `v.id`

Call the method `getId()` It will return the view's identifier.

Ex:

```
v.getId()
```

That is:

```
if(v.getId() == R.id.play){ 

//statements 

}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId()

Comment: I think you meant `if(v.getId() == R.id.play)`

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I feel a bit silly now. Can't accept the answer until 5 mins but I will when I can.

Answer (score 0):

You should use .getId() instead of .id

Like this:

```
v.getId();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try importing your app's R file, like:

```
import com.coursework.R;
```

Comment: Never do that. It isn't necessary and can cause more problems than it solves. The package's own R.java class is "imported" implicitly.

Comment: That unfortunate didn't change anything. Still getting the same errors.

Comment: @user3037567 : JoelFernandes has posted the correct solution.