# Eclipse id cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, eclipse

I get this irritating `id cannot be resolved or is not a field` with R.id only, and not R.layout. When I click on the x it says no suggestions, and it is referencing the field correctly (blue & italic).

I've tried cleaning, building, restarting, deleting R, fixing imports. Nothing works.

**Following is my code :**

```
package com.example.helloworld;
import com.example.helloworld.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class NameGetter extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b){
        Button btn;
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.namegetter);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        if (btn != null){
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String name = "";
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        if (et != null){
            name = et.getText().toString();
        }
        i.putExtra("n", name);
        this.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

How can I determine the source of this error?

Comment: ... and you'll have even more troubles!! ;)

Comment: Clean your project and run it again.

Comment: Problem may be in your main.xml file.

Comment: Try hitting Ctrl + Shift + F in your layout file. Sometimes ir produces weird unseen errors. Save the file, and hopefully it will regenerate R.java with the layout components.

Comment: is there any errors in your resource files.??

Comment: first check that there is an error in resources or not or in manifest file, if exist then resolve that error else remove your R file and clean your project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["id cannot be resolved or is not a field" error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296047/id-cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-a-field-error)

Answer (score 1):

also: remove "import android.R" from imports at top of file (if there)

Answer (score 0):

Delete "`import com.example.helloworld.R;`" and then press `ctrl+shift+letter "O"`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thnx for the help, but it wasn't actually ther, i addedit trying to fix the error. I already tried every common solution. I was hoping for a more out of the box solution.

Answer (score 0):

First  Clean Your Project and Debug after that id cannot be resolved then 
 check the android Target Version from Project Properties (rite click on project => select Properties =>Select Android)
and then check in android sdk Manager (This same version installed or not with correct api)
Your Problem will solve