# color can not be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android

I am fallowing a tutorial and have an error on `color` saying "color can not be resolved or is not a field". Anyone know the reason for this. Thanks.

```
lv.setBackgroundColor(callerActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.Twitter_blue));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["id cannot be resolved or is not a field" error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296047/id-cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-a-field-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open "colors.xml" file under the "values" folder and add the color:

```
 <color name="Twitter_blue">#FF4081</color>
```

with the relevant colour hex number.

Answer (score 1):

`Twitter_blue` apparently is not a field in `R.color` have you tried just using `R.color.blue` or something similar?